# Regex in PreviewTextInput: only decimals between 0.0 and 1.0

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, textbox, decimal

I'd like to have a regex, which only allows digits between 0.0 and 1.0 in a textbox.

BUT it should be in the method PreviewTextInput (C#, WPF project)

So the normal regex doesn't work

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^0|0.0|0\.[0-9]*|1\.0|1$");
```

I've found a regex, which allows all decimals in the PreviewTextInput method:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-1.]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$");
```

How can a change this regex to only accept decimals between 0-1?

Thanks.

My method for decimals:

```
private void tb_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-1.]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$");
        e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text));
    }
```

My method for decimals between 0-1 (doesn't work):

```
        private void tb_Surface_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(0?\.[0-9]+|1\.0)$");
        e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
       // e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text));

    }
```

Comment: Just one digit after dot? 0 and 1 can be matched?

Comment: no, any digits after dot

Comment: Please check if [`^(0?\.[0-9]+|1\.0)$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(0%3f%5c.%5b0-9%5d%2b%7c1%5c.0)%5cr%3f%24&i=0.0999903%0d%0a.994564575%0d%0a2235346%0d%0a0.236767876765784587686758%0d%0a1.0&o=m) works for you.

Comment: no this regex doesn't work for me

Comment: It seems you used this regex when key press,not after the text whole changed?

Comment: yes. it checks for every char you enter. and this is my problem. I would like to have a regex, which is PreviewTextInput, so the user can only press the keys, which are allowed.  And not the way to check the text from the textbox after all digits were entered

Comment: the first method "tb_PreviewTextInput" worked for any decimal, so I 'd like to have this regex, but only for digits between 0.0-1.0. Isn't there any way to transform this one, to a specific range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@"^(0(?:\.\d+)?|1(?:\.0+)?)$"
```

`0` and `1` also can be matched,if you don't want match them,and must have any digits after dot ,you can use

```
@"^(0\.\d+|1\.0+)$"
```

The code below is what you want,and you need to remove the last `dot` when the textbox lost focus,such as `str.Trim('.')`

```
private void tb_Surface_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var patten = @"^(0(\.\d*)?|1(\.0*)?)$";
    Regex regex = new Regex(patten);
    e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    // e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch((sender as TextBox).Text.Insert((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text));
}
```

Comment: same problem as @Avinash Raj, it doesn't work for the method PreviewTextInput :(

Comment: you can have a try now

Comment: so I copied your new method and add "((TextBox)sender).Text = tb.Text.Trim('.');"  to the method LostFocus. But the textbox allows only "0" and "1"

Comment: IT WORKS. but with the second e.Handled !

Answer (score 1):

You may try this regex.

```
@"^(?:0?\.[0-9]+|1\.0)$"
```

Comment: you the one asked for `0-1`, you mean this `@"^(?:0\.[0-9]|1\.0|0|1)$"`

Comment: @Entchen post valid and invalid matches.

Comment: this one only allows 0 and 1

Comment: @Entchen who said that? just make the ifrst zero as optional `0?` if you want to allow `.12`

Comment: my textbox said it. I tried this regex, but I could only add 0 or 1 to it, but no dot or other digits

Comment: if I would check for regex match after textbox lost focus, it would be ok, but not for PreviewTextInput

Comment: @Entchen: so the problem doesn't come from the pattern now.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte but it is not the right pattern for PreviewTextInput. after every key you press, the method checks for match or not

Answer (score 1):

About `@"^0|0.0|0\.[0-9]*|1\.0|1$"`: there are two mistakes:

1) one of the dot is not escaped, so it can match any characters.
 2) The `^` and `$` are only respectively in the first and last branches of your alternation, but are not in factor with each branch. To do that you must put all branches in a non capturing group.

About `"^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-1.]*[.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$"`: the first branch is ok, the second branch is false.

1) `[0-1.]*` that can be written `[01.]*` *(there is no characters between 0 and 1, no need to put a range)* allow any combination of `0`, `1` and `.`: `1111111111`, `10100010` or `1.00.111..`. Not sure that allowing the dot here is a good idea.
2) `[.,]{0,1}` that can be written `[.,]?`: why this time you want to allow the comma?
3) `[.,]{0,1}[0-9]*$` if the dot (or the comma) is optional, this subpattern can match any integer because of the `[0-9]*`.

I think you must consider using non-capturing groups to build your pattern. Starting from your first pattern seems to be the best option. Anyway, the first job is to clearly define what are the allowed formats.

Comment: I didn't use regex anytime before and have no idea, how they really work, thie first one was a internet-solution. and the second one was my try :D So how would you create the regex for digits between 0 and 1 ?  I allow the comma, because in germany it is the separator for decimals, so I would like the user to have the choice to write decimals with a dot or comma

Comment: allowed formats are all decimals between 0.0 and 1.0 (incl.) alternative formats for 0.0 and 1.0 are "0" and "1". ( and all dots can be replaced by commas)

Comment: @Entchen: Even with this kind of description, your requirements stay too broad! is `0.0000000` allowed? or `.1`, `0.`, `1.`? How many possible digits after the dot?