# Realtime validation and formatting of textbox input with regex

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have WPF application where the users are able to change the product number of a product connected to the computer with USB. The sticker on the product lists the product number in this format: 111 22 33-44.

Today the users may only enter digits (111223344) in the textbox. The input is validated with regex that checks for nine digits. But now the client wants the users to be able to either:

1. Enter the number as digits only and format the string as it is being typed. When the user has typed "1112" it should automatically be formatted as "111 2" in the textbox and so on. When user has entered all nine digits it should look like 111 22 33-44
2. Enter the number as it is written on the sticker (with spaces, etc).

But at the same time the product number must be validated to include only nine digits. The spaces and "-" must be invisible

I could've easily solved this in code, but the problem here is that this validation/formatting must be fully configurable in a config file. There are various categories of products that can be serviced by this application and the format of the product number may vary.

Is this solvable in a fairly easy way with regex? I really can't see how i can combine the two, validation and formatting:

- ^\d{9}$ - for validating nine digits
- (\w{3})(\w{2})?(\w{2})?(\w{2})? - for formatting together with replacement pattern $1 $2 $3-$4. This pattern does however only format nine digits without spaces and "-"

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

It seems like i would need to use at least three regex patterns for this to work:

1. for validating the valid product number (not the display value). Is it 9 digits?
2. for formatting the display value (123456789 = 123 45 67-89)
3. stripping the added characters from the formatting (blanks and -)

Maybe a simpler solution would be to keep the current validation (for example ^\d{9}$) that validates the raw value, and then simply add a setting called DisplayMask where the people that are responsible for the configuration can enter something like this:

- "### ## ##-##"

And then i write code that uses this mask for formatting the display value. This has several advantages:

1. Very easy to understand for the people responsible for the configurations
2. This will also enable me to easily retrieve all character that needs to be stripped from the entered value by simply getting the displaymask and remove all #. The characters that are left are the ones that must be stripped from the product number before they're written to the product hardware.
3. Also makes it very easy to set the max length of the textbox. Max length of product number raw value + number of added characters from display mask.

Comment: You can't do that in single step. Validate numbers only with `^\d{9}$`. When the value changes, remove all non-digits (it is possible without regex: `input = new String(input.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())`), validate, and display as formatted with your second regex. Validate upon submit with the updated second expression: `^\d{3}[ ]\d{2}[ ]\d{2}-\d{2}$`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one [Regex in PreviewTextInput: only decimals between 0.0 and 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406578/regex-in-previewtextinput-only-decimals-between-0-0-and-1-0/31407000#31407000)

you can use `PreviewTextInput` event here,then use `Regex.Replace` to set the format, here is an example

```
string inputStr = "111223";//e.Text;
inputStr = Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"\D", string.Empty);
if (inputStr.Length > 0)
{
    inputStr = inputStr.Substring(0, Math.Min(9, inputStr.Length));
    List<string[]> tmp = new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "7", "-" }, new string[] { "5", " " }, new string[] { "3", " " } };
    foreach (var arr in tmp)
    {
        inputStr = Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"(?<=^\d{" + arr[0] + "})", arr[1]);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(inputStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to make this configurable, the key is the [`Regex` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

Storing the regular expression in an external config file could then be easily imported and used in matching, such as `Regex.IsMatch()`, especially [`IsMatch(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of the regex class. My question is more regarding of how to solve this specific problem with Regex.

Answer (score 0):

First off, after the text is formatted you have an entry with a length of 12.  I would set the `TextBox.MaxLength = 12` to limit the amount of data that can be entered.

As far as validating, there's probably a "cleaner" way of doing this, but to start with you can have a series of `Regex.IsMatch()` conditions that will auto format the input.

For example:

```
1112       => 111 2
111 223    => 111 22 3
111 22 334 => 111 22 33-4
```

Then there's a final `Regex.IsMatch()` check that the input is in the format of

```
### ## ##-##
```

Code Sample:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = textBox1.Text;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\d{4}"))
    {
        textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(text, "(\\d{3})(\\d)", "$1 $2");
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\d{3} \\d{3}"))
    {
        textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(text, "(\\d{3} \\d{2})(\\d)", "$1 $2");
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\d{3} \\d{2} \\d{3}"))
    {
        textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(text, "(\\d{3} \\d{2} \\d{2})(\\d)", "$1-$2");
    }
    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\d{3} \\d{2} \\d{2}-\\d{2}"))
    {
        // Invalid entry
    }

    // Keep the cursor at the end of the input
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
}
```